# Weird Crash on UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, realm, google-fabric

I have a published app and I see in Fabric a crash with this log:

```
EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION 0x00000000a21403e1

#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  UIKit                          0x18d199e28 +[UIViewController existingNibNameMatchingClassName:bundle:] + 308
1  UIKit                          0x18d199c1c -[UIViewController nibName] + 300
2  UIKit                          0x18d228fec -[UIViewController loadView] + 40
3  UIKit                          0x18d14db14 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 172
4  UIKit                          0x18d14da50 -[UIViewController view] + 28
5  UIKit                          0x18d13ece4 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 136
6  UIKit                          0x18d13db18 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 272
7  UIKit                          0x18d1cb62c -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 48
8  UIKit                          0x18d141274 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3660
9  UIKit                          0x18d10e5e0 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1680
10 UIKit                          0x18d73eb1c __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 784
11 UIKit                          0x18d10ddd0 +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 160
12 UIKit                          0x18d10dc6c -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 240
13 UIKit                          0x18d10cafc -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 724
14 UIKit                          0x18dda284c __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 296
15 UIKit                          0x18d10c1ec -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 432
16 UIKit                          0x18db87ac8 __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 220
17 UIKit                          0x18dcd5bf8 _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 112
18 UIKit                          0x18d10bc0c -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 248
19 UIKit                          0x18d10b5a8 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 368
20 UIKit                          0x18d1085e0 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 540
21 UIKit                          0x18d108330 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 364
22 FrontBoardServices             0x185d34470 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 364
23 FrontBoardServices             0x185d3cd6c __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 224
24 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e24a60 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
25 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e2c170 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 224
26 FrontBoardServices             0x185d68878 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
27 FrontBoardServices             0x185d6851c -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 404
28 FrontBoardServices             0x185d68ab8 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
29 CoreFoundation                 0x1834db404 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
30 CoreFoundation                 0x1834dac2c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 276
31 CoreFoundation                 0x1834d879c __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
32 CoreFoundation                 0x1833f8da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
33 GraphicsServices               0x1853de020 GSEventRunModal + 100
34 UIKit                          0x18d418758 UIApplicationMain + 236
35 libdyld.dylib                  0x182e89fc0 start + 4

--

#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  UIKit                          0x18d199e28 +[UIViewController existingNibNameMatchingClassName:bundle:] + 308
1  UIKit                          0x18d199c1c -[UIViewController nibName] + 300
2  UIKit                          0x18d228fec -[UIViewController loadView] + 40
3  UIKit                          0x18d14db14 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 172
4  UIKit                          0x18d14da50 -[UIViewController view] + 28
5  UIKit                          0x18d13ece4 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 136
6  UIKit                          0x18d13db18 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 272
7  UIKit                          0x18d1cb62c -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 48
8  UIKit                          0x18d141274 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3660
9  UIKit                          0x18d10e5e0 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1680
10 UIKit                          0x18d73eb1c __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 784
11 UIKit                          0x18d10ddd0 +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 160
12 UIKit                          0x18d10dc6c -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 240
13 UIKit                          0x18d10cafc -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 724
14 UIKit                          0x18dda284c __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 296
15 UIKit                          0x18d10c1ec -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 432
16 UIKit                          0x18db87ac8 __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 220
17 UIKit                          0x18dcd5bf8 _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 112
18 UIKit                          0x18d10bc0c -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 248
19 UIKit                          0x18d10b5a8 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 368
20 UIKit                          0x18d1085e0 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 540
21 UIKit                          0x18d108330 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 364
22 FrontBoardServices             0x185d34470 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 364
23 FrontBoardServices             0x185d3cd6c __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 224
24 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e24a60 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
25 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e2c170 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 224
26 FrontBoardServices             0x185d68878 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
27 FrontBoardServices             0x185d6851c -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 404
28 FrontBoardServices             0x185d68ab8 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
29 CoreFoundation                 0x1834db404 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
30 CoreFoundation                 0x1834dac2c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 276
31 CoreFoundation                 0x1834d879c __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
32 CoreFoundation                 0x1833f8da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
33 GraphicsServices               0x1853de020 GSEventRunModal + 100
34 UIKit                          0x18d418758 UIApplicationMain + 236
35 libdyld.dylib                  0x182e89fc0 start + 4

#1. Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183157b04 start_wqthread + 122

#2. io.answers.EventQueue (QOS: BACKGROUND)
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182fb8550 __getdirentries64 + 8
1  libsystem_c.dylib              0x182ecf944 _readdir_unlocked + 128
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x182ecf8a8 readdir + 40
3  CoreFoundation                 0x18342c1ec _CFIterateDirectory + 100
4  CoreFoundation                 0x18343cb50 _CFBundleReadDirectory + 316
5  CoreFoundation                 0x1834a5714 _createQueryTableAtPath + 480
6  CoreFoundation                 0x1834a5358 _copyQueryTable + 312
7  CoreFoundation                 0x1834a4868 _copyResourceURLsFromBundle + 332
8  CoreFoundation                 0x18343c288 _CFBundleCopyFindResources + 1312
9  CoreFoundation                 0x18343bd5c CFBundleCopyResourceURL + 60
10 CoreFoundation                 0x1835803e8 _copyStringFromTable + 248
11 CoreFoundation                 0x18358002c CFBundleCopyLocalizedStringForLocalization + 128
12 Foundation                     0x183e8b54c -[NSBundle localizedStringForKey:value:table:] + 60
13 Foundation                     0x183ec4cfc -[NSFileManager _URLForReplacingItemAtURL:error:] + 1288
14 Foundation                     0x183f5f610 _NSCreateTemporaryFile_Protected + 508
15 Foundation                     0x183ec4300 _NSWriteDataToFileWithExtendedAttributes + 440
16 MyApplication                       0x10308d2ac +[ANSCrashMetadata writeSerializedDictionary:toURL:] (ANSCrashMetadata.m:32)
17 MyApplication                       0x10308e2f0 -[ANSRotateCrashMetadataOperation main] (ANSRotateCrashMetadataOperation.m:47)
18 MyApplication                       0x10309ab28 -[ANSAnswersController replacePreviousExecutionMetadataWithCurrentMetadata:inRootDirectory:] (ANSAnswersController.m:272)
19 MyApplication                       0x1030999d0 __56-[ANSAnswersController initWithBetaToken:rootDirectory:]_block_invoke (ANSAnswersController.m:103)
20 Foundation                     0x183f5ae88 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
21 Foundation                     0x183e9c8d0 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 72
22 Foundation                     0x183e9bcac -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 848
23 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e24a60 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
24 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e2c170 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 224
25 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e24a60 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
26 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e2c170 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 224
27 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e2c05c dispatch_block_perform$VARIANT$mp + 104
28 Foundation                     0x183f5c750 __NSOQSchedule_f + 376
29 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e24a60 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
30 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e2ce94 _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$mp + 424
31 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e2b7cc _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 604
32 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e31cac _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 588
33 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e319fc _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 120
34 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183157fac _pthread_wqthread + 1176
35 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183157b08 start_wqthread + 4

#3. com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182f97de8 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182f97c60 mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1834dae40 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1834d8908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1568
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1833f8da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
5  Foundation                     0x183e6d674 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6  Foundation                     0x183e6d4dc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 84
7  UIKit                          0x18d0fd768 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8  Foundation                     0x183f7defc __NSThread__start__ + 1040
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183159220 _pthread_body + 272
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183159110 _pthread_body + 290
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183157b10 thread_start + 4

#4. com.apple.CoreLocation.ConnectionClient.0x1c4127b20.events
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182f97e3c semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x182e2702c _dispatch_sema4_timedwait$VARIANT$mp + 60
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x182e278a0 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 72
3  CoreLocation                   0x189cbb888 CLClientInvalidate + 888
4  CoreLocation                   0x189cc143c CLClientRetrieveData + 1744
5  CoreLocation                   0x189cc111c CLClientRetrieveData + 944
6  CoreLocation                   0x189d17928 CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 79000
7  CoreLocation                   0x189d13988 CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 62712
8  CoreLocation                   0x189d13850 CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 62400
9  CoreLocation                   0x189d152ac CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 69148
10 libxpc.dylib                   0x183192f30 _xpc_connection_call_event_handler + 68
11 libxpc.dylib                   0x1831908c4 _xpc_connection_mach_event + 984
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e24b30 _dispatch_client_callout4 + 16
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e3b440 _dispatch_mach_msg_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 352
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e2e86c _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 280
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e3beec _dispatch_mach_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 508
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e2e86c _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 280
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e2f2fc _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 336
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e2e86c _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 280
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e2f2fc _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 336
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e2fcc8 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$mp + 340
21 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e38098 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$mp + 668
22 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183157e70 _pthread_wqthread + 860
23 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183157b08 start_wqthread + 4

#5. com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.binary-images
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182f9989c write + 8
1  MyApplication                       0x103082abc CLSFileLoopWithWriteBlock (CLSFile.m:212)
2  MyApplication                       0x103082cc8 CLSFileWriteToFileDescriptorOrBuffer (CLSFile.m:190)
3  MyApplication                       0x103082fa8 CLSFileWriteCollectionStart (CLSFile.m:438)
4  MyApplication                       0x103082eac CLSFileWriteSectionStart (CLSFile.m:418)
5  MyApplication                       0x10306abe4 __CLSBinaryImageChanged_block_invoke (CLSBinaryImage.m:501)
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x182e24aa0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x182e24a60 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x182e2e9b4 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 608
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x182e2f2fc _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 336
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e2fcc8 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$mp + 340
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e38098 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$mp + 668
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183157e70 _pthread_wqthread + 860
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183157b08 start_wqthread + 4

#6. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182fb9d78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183157eb4 _pthread_wqthread + 928
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183157b08 start_wqthread + 4

#7. RLMRealm notification listener
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182f9c32c kevent + 8
1  Realm                          0x103ca6130 realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::listen() (external_commit_helper.cpp:203)
2  Realm                          0x103ca6a9c std::__1::__async_func<realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::ExternalCommitHelper(realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator&)::$_0>::operator()() (future:2323)
3  Realm                          0x103ca6a24 std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::ExternalCommitHelper(realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator&)::$_0> >::__execute() (future:1041)
4  Realm                          0x103ca6bd4 std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::ExternalCommitHelper(realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator&)::$_0> >::*)(), std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::ExternalCommitHelper(realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator&)::$_0> >*> >(void*, void*) (memory:2549)
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183159220 _pthread_body + 272
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183159110 _pthread_body + 290
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183157b10 thread_start + 4

#8. com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
0  MyApplication                       0x103083b94 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads (CLSProcess.c:376)
1  MyApplication                       0x103084054 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads (CLSProcess.c:407)
2  MyApplication                       0x103073898 CLSHandler (CLSHandler.m:26)
3  MyApplication                       0x10306ec88 CLSMachExceptionServer (CLSMachException.c:446)
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183159220 _pthread_body + 272
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183159110 _pthread_body + 290
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183157b10 thread_start + 4

#9. GAIThread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182f97de8 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182f97c60 mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1834dae40 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1834d8908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1568
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1833f8da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
5  Foundation                     0x183e6d674 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6  Foundation                     0x183ee21a8 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 88
7  MyApplication                       0x10304ee18 +[GAI threadMain:] (GAI.m:241)
8  Foundation                     0x183f7defc __NSThread__start__ + 1040
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183159220 _pthread_body + 272
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183159110 _pthread_body + 290
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183157b10 thread_start + 4

#10. com.google.fira.worker
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182f991e0 pread + 8
1  libsqlite3.dylib               0x1839d0b68 sqlite3_rekey + 5532
2  libsqlite3.dylib               0x183932cd4 sqlite3_snprintf + 12356
3  libsqlite3.dylib               0x18394e850 sqlite3_finalize + 11416
4  libsqlite3.dylib               0x18394d960 sqlite3_finalize + 7592
5  libsqlite3.dylib               0x18394853c sqlite3_exec + 81780
6  libsqlite3.dylib               0x18394815c sqlite3_exec + 80788
7  libsqlite3.dylib               0x18394141c sqlite3_exec + 52820
8  libsqlite3.dylib               0x183938b5c sqlite3_exec + 17812
9  libsqlite3.dylib               0x183936134 sqlite3_exec + 7020
10 libsqlite3.dylib               0x1839352fc sqlite3_exec + 3380
11 libsqlite3.dylib               0x183935030 sqlite3_exec + 2664
12 MyApplication                       0x1030c539c -[FIRASqliteStore prepareSQL:error:] + 4341011356
13 MyApplication                       0x1030c592c -[FIRASqliteStore validateDatabaseWithError:] + 4341012780
14 MyApplication                       0x1030c584c -[FIRASqliteStore openAndValidateDatabase:] + 4341012556
15 MyApplication                       0x1030c0f60 -[FIRASqliteStore initWithDatabasePath:] + 4340993888
16 MyApplication                       0x1030d85c4 -[FIRADatabase initializeDatabaseResourcesWithContext:databasePath:] + 4341089732
17 MyApplication                       0x1030cddb4 -[FIRADatabase initWithDatabaseName:persistedConfig:] + 4341046708
18 MyApplication                       0x1030de6d8 __48-[FIRAMeasurement startMeasurementOnWorkerQueue]_block_invoke + 4341114584
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e24a60 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e28268 dispatch_once_f$VARIANT$mp + 60
21 MyApplication                       0x1030de4dc -[FIRAMeasurement startMeasurementOnWorkerQueue] + 4341114076
22 MyApplication                       0x1030de274 -[FIRAMeasurement setEnabledOnWorkerQueue:] + 4341113460
23 MyApplication                       0x1030f5a54 __52-[FIRAScheduler scheduleOnWorkerQueueBlockID:block:]_block_invoke + 4341209684
24 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e24aa0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
25 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e24a60 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
26 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e2e9b4 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 608
27 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e2f2fc _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 336
28 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e2fcc8 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$mp + 340
29 libdispatch.dylib              0x182e38098 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$mp + 668
30 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183157e70 _pthread_wqthread + 860
31 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183157b08 start_wqthread + 4

#11. Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183157b04 start_wqthread + 122
```

I'm not sure if anyone can understand anything about this crash with the above log, I know therefore that it happening right after the splash screen.

Inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in `AppDelegate` I set up:

Firebase

Fabric

Location

PushNotification

and
Realm with this code:

```
// Reset Realm if the scheme has changed
do {
    _ = try Realm()
} catch {
    let configuration = Realm.Configuration(deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: true)
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = configuration
}
```

Comment: Is `Preferences.lastDateDownloadedRoucourses` correct? `lastDateDownloadedRoucourses` (Roucourses?)?

Comment: @Akaino this is just a userdefaults value

Comment: Yeah I know. It just sounds like a typo to me. Does it exist?

Comment: The app is on the appStore there is not a typo it crashes to only one user

Comment: Ok. Well it's hard to get anything off this error without actual code. Are you able to retrieve a full error log from anywhere? Including exception codes, demystified?

Comment: If i download the file log from fabric I can retrieve some more information but its pretty similar with the above I have

Comment: At least the exception type would be helpful. Should look like this `Exception Type:  00000020
 Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
 Highlighted Thread:  0`

Comment: @Akaino I edited my question with the full log.

Comment: Phew. Bad instruction is pretty generic. I think without code there's not much to help. At least I can't. Sorry!

Comment: @Akaino thanks for your interest

Answer (score 0):

There have been [related fixes to FirebaseAnalytics](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/1487) in the past few months.  There's a good chance that updating to at least Firebase 5.5.0 will eliminate this crash.